# Input field iOS Safari bug — Can't type in any text

Tags: ios, css, forms, input, safari

I have a custom styled text input in a form on a page.

It's working as expected on desktop, Android, iOS Chrome, but sometimes in iOS Safari when typing into the box, no text enters, even though the field has focus and the cursor is flashing (doesn't happen very often, but seems to happen all the time for some users).

The form code is very standard, (copied straight from Mailchimp)

```
<form action="[mailchimp subscribe url]" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Email" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="REQUEST INVITE" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_e563c0e6b5344e25de276c14f_5e5c7a08a6" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The custom CSS is:

```
input.email, .button {
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Calibre Medium';
    color: white !important;
    opacity: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


::placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-moz-placeholder, :-ms-placeholder, input.email, .button {
    color: white !important;
    transition: all 0.15s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

Has anyone else seen this before?

I'm using flexbox and there is an animated SVG on the page, which I know sometimes causes unusual behavior in iOS Safari...

Comment: Ever get this figured out? I am experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Hey @GarrettWills, I did a hack where I set the field to display none, then back to display '' after a 0sec timeout. Pretty nasty, but it worked.

Comment: Haha alright I'll give that a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will solve the issue:

```
input, textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

By default in safari browser, `user-select:text` does not work. We need to provide the browser-specific `-webkit-user-select:text` property.

https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_user-select

Comment: Mac Catalyst UPDATE: dismissKeyboard gesture trick must be excluded

Comment: 2022 and still fixing this issue. Just saved the day for me. Well done +1

Answer (score 9):

#### Browser specific css rules for text input field

```
input {
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: text; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div tag should be display-block and clear both.

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI it should be applied to `textarea` elements as well as basic `input` elements as I found the same problem with `textarea`:

e.g.

```
input, textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```