# iOS input field - when typing text is invisible

Tags: ios, css, input, sass, mobile-safari

There's something wrong with various input fields, when I type on iOS mobile safari (only) the text is invisible.

However for this section of the site, I cannot target via CSS it as it's an iframe.

Any ideas of

1. why does this happen?
2. how to resolve it?

I have to force a blur or the GPU by adding `transform: translateZ(0);` in order to resolve it.  However I cannot use CSS on this element.

[image: gif of issue]

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851413/input-field-ios-safari-bug-cant-type-in-any-text ?

Comment: Try to apply CSS with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714880/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe-content

Comment: I can't target the element's CSS so I can't add this property.  Looking at the `input` CSS there is `user-select: text !important;`so I'm not sure this is it..

Comment: I attempted to use JS to target but i feel like it's layering unstable fixes instead of resolving the original issue..

Answer (score 1):

Placing

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Causes the issue, I believe it's due to the way Safari handles scrolling / layering with this switched on.  The way to fix it is to force the GPU using

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

On the parent element that can be controlled.