# react safari can't focus on input when clicked

Tags: html, reactjs, safari

I'm creating a search bar like so:

```
<form
  id="search-bar-form"
  onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }}
>
  <div id="search-bar-div">
    <input
     onChange={async e => {
       console.log("I was changed");//debug
         // Set the search term
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        // Fetch results
        await debouncedSearch(e.target.value);
      }}
      onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
      type="text"
      name="search"
      id="search-bar"
      aria-label="search"
      value={searchTerm}
      list="search-bar-autocomplete"
      autoComplete="off"
      placeholder={` ${t('searchbar.default-value')}`}
    />
    <div>
      <ul id="search-bar-autocomplete">
        {searchResults &&
          searchResults.length > 0 &&
          searchResults.map((result, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              style={
                selectionIndex === index
                  ? {
                      backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
                    }
                  : null
              }
              onClick={() => {
                const selectedItem = searchResults[index];
                setSearchTerm(selectedItem.name);
                handleItemSelected(selectedItem);
              }}
            >
              {result.name}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In Safari, and Safari only, I am not able to click in the input at all; I don't even see the cursor in there.

This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851413/input-field-ios-safari-bug-cant-type-in-any-text#), because in this question the input can be selected and the cursor appears but they can't type. Even though it's not the same problem I did try the solution suggested in that question, which is to add the propertyy `-webkit-user-select:text`to the input, and it didn't work.

Question: why can't I focus in my input and how do I make it possible?

Comment: hi @jimboweb did you get anywhere on this? I'm having weird behavior on a safari autocomplete as well.

Answer (score 0):

I propose `user-select: text;`. The webkit version is a polyfill.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).