# Flask Input fields do not allow text input in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flask-wtforms

I'm  using flask form to create a form page. The input fields work in Chrome and Edge. But do not work in safari (cannot click in input text).

The following is the inspector HTML:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

[image]

I've been trying to get this to work, Ive tried:
[Cannot write into input field on safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889003/cannot-write-into-input-field-on-safari)
and [Input field iOS Safari bug — Can't type in any text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851413/input-field-ios-safari-bug-cant-type-in-any-text)

And both do not help. Any ideas of what could be wrong ?

Here is a sample of the code im using to create the form:

```
thing_name = StringField(
        'Name',
        description='Name of the thing',
        validators=[
            InputRequired('Please specify the name of the thing'),
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the form name. For some reason it cannot be named `title`, changing the name fixed the issue.